How to position an icon on right-bottom of button without setting height to container
How to position an icon on right-bottom of a Container that wraps a button, without setting a height to the Container?
I'm trying to use Stack, without success. As suggested in many answers, I cannot set a height to the Container because, then, depending on the size of my text, it gets truncated (and I need the whole text to be shown (it is a choice in a trivia app)). See the snippet and print below to see what happens in this case:
1) Setting a height to the container (does not work):
The Icon goes to bottom-right, but the text gets truncated:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget choiceSelectedButton = Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          child: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('test test test test test test test test')),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.check_circle,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: choiceSelectedButton),
    );
  }
}



Then I have tried to remove the height and tried wrapping both the Container and the Icon in Expanded, Flexible, FittedBox (even if it woudn't make sense):
2) Removing height property from container (does not work):
Now, the text does not truncate, but the icon gets out of position:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget choiceSelectedButton = Container(
    width: 100,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          child: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('test test test test test test test test')),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.check_circle,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: choiceSelectedButton),
    );
  }
}



How can I do that?
Questions searched:
How to put an icon in the bottom right edge of container in flutter
icon at bottom right corner flutter
Place an icon on the buttom right of a Container
(but solutions are to set height)
Flutter position button bottom very right?
(spacer() does not work)
Flutter container to position bottom right
alignment property does not work
How to position an Icon/Button at the Top Right corner of a Container in FLUTTER?
simpply didn't work
icon at bottom right corner flutter
(but solution is not to set height and therefore problem 2 happens)

First, let's examine why your initial approaches didn't work.
1. Setting a fixed height on the container
This limits the height of the button, causing the text to truncate if it exceeds the container's set height.
2. Removing the height from the container
When you remove the height constraint, the Stack expands to fill all available space vertically (essentially double.infinity), which makes the icon positioning unpredictable since the Stack has no defined boundaries.
Now, here are two alternative solutions that can help position the icon correctly without setting a fixed height.
First Solution:
Stack(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      width: 100, // Set the width of the button here
      child: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('test test test test test test test test'),
      ),
    ),
    const Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, // Aligns the icon to the bottom-right of the button
        child: Icon(
          Icons.check_circle,
          color: Colors.green,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)

By removing the outer Container and setting the button's width directly with SizedBox, we allow the Stack to only take up the necessary space. Positioned.fill adjusts the Icon's constraints to match the largest child within the Stack (the button), ensuring it aligns correctly at the bottom-right.
Second Solution:
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, // Sets default alignment for all Stack children
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      width: 100, // Set the width of the button here
      child: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('test test test test test test test test'),
      ),
    ),
    const Icon(
      Icons.check_circle,
      color: Colors.green,
      size: 30,
    ),
  ],
)

By setting alignment: Alignment.bottomRight on the Stack, we automatically align the icon to the bottom-right of the Stack, simplifying the code by removing the Align widget.
For a better understanding of constraints, I highly recommend exploring this article in the Flutter documentation.

Thanks! It worked. I didn't know using a sizedbox  would make the stack to only take up the necessary space. Anyway, really simple answer, which makes it awesome. Thanks again!

@vacosti I'm glad it worked for you! The key here isn’t specifically the SizedBox; a Container would work too. The important part is that we set the constraints on the button itself rather than on the Stack, allowing it to size correctly based on the button’s dimensions.
